# How to store (x,y) Coordinates in python and be able to update them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment where i need to be able to take a digital signal input of x and y axis and be able to manipulate it by shifting or scaling or inverting the signal (i.e do mathematical operations on the x-axis)

So what I've done is take an x and y input and store them as a tuple in a list (a list of tuples) but tuples are unchangeable so I'm looking for a way to deal with this or an alternative solution

edit:my bad this code is after i tried using a list of lists but i still don't know how to change the values of the nested list

```py
coordinates=[]
x,y=input().split(',')
x=int(x)
y=int(y)
coordinates.append([x,y])
```

Comment: Your code creates a list of lists. Should be what you want.

Comment: Have you *tried* changing coordinates as you seem to be storing them?  If it didn't work, please given details.

Comment: I'm sorry but bare with me, I'm a total newbie to python so i'm still figuring things out so i dont really know how to change the nested list

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable; lists are not.  So you could use a list of lists.